# Show that $\sum (-1)^n x^{(2^n)}$ has no limit as $x \uparrow 1$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, summation, power-series

> Show that the following limit does not exist: $$\sum_{0}^{\infty} (-1)^n x^{(2^n)}\text{ with }x \uparrow 1$$

I tried setting $$f(x) = x - x^2 + x^4 - x^8...$$ then $$f(x) = x-f(x^2)$$  then the limit if it exists should be $$l=1-l\text{ so that }l=\frac{1}{2}$$

Also $$f(x)= x-x^2+f(x^4)$$
But after that I am stuck...

Comment: Sorry, what does the upward arrow mean?

Comment: It means x tends to 1 from below eg 0.9,0.99,0.999,0.99999... the sum does converge for any x<1

Comment: how about this: the last equality shows that $f(x^4) \lt f(x)$ and i find $f(0.99) = 0.494098495228309 \lt 0.5 $ in Excel therefore there is a subsequence that does not converge to  0.5, therefore the  series does not converge. I know it is cheating a little bit ...